# Mock a class in another class in C# unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

For example,

I have a class defined in somewhere else:

```
using ...;

namespace abc.Client
{
    public class ByoIpClient : ServiceClient<ByoIpClient>
    {
        public static ByoIpClient CreateByoIpClient(SomeSettings someSettings);
    }
}
```

And it was used in my project like

```
    using abc.Client; //using the class defined above
    public class BYOIPManager
    {
        private ByoIpClient byoIpClient;
        public void Start()
        {
            this.byoIpClient = ByoIpClient.CreateByoIpClient(someSettings);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to write a test for the class BYOIPManager, But I don't want to use the defined byoIpClient. But I want to write another mockByoipClient to replace the ByoipClient class. How could I do that? Thanks!

```
[TestClass]
    public class BYOIPOrchestrationEngineTests
    {
        private BYOIPManager byoipManager;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInitialize()
        {
            this.byoipManager = new BYOIPManager();
            // I need this byoIpManager to use my mockByoIpClient rather than the real byoIpClient
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should change your manger class to inject the client in a constructor, then you can pass in a mock instead of the real thing.

Comment: As you can see, it is created from a static class and CreateByoIpClient() would be called multiple times elsewhere. So It would be great I can use it everywhere in the class rather than just in the constructor.

Comment: If you really can't change the static class that is calling `CreateByoIpClient`, then make an interface with the same methods.  Have a real implementation that just funnels the calls through to the static class.  Then, inject that interface into your application.  Then you can mock it easily.

Comment: What IoC container are you using?

Comment: @Jonesopolis Could you make it clear how to do that? like, writing a answer?

Comment: sure @WeihengLi

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was getting at in my comment.  Say your static class, that you cannot edit, is this (dumbed down):

```
public static class ByoIpClient 
{
    public static string DoWork(string settings)
    {
        return "real work"
    }
}
```

Create an interface with the same method signature:

```
public interface IByoIpClient
{
    string DoWork(string settings);
}
```

Then create a class that implements your interface, and just passes through to the static class:

```
public class InjectableByoIpClient : IByoIpClient
{
    public string DoWork(string settings) => ByoIpClient.DoWork(settings);
}
```

Now you can set up this class with DI, and accept the interface in the constructor of the `BYOIPManager`

Comment: I think 'how to set up Dependency Injection' is really a question unto itself